# I am trying to create a program with a class called Investment, and the object returns Interest rate and Principal

Tags: python-3.x

I am just a newbie in Python and trying to write this program. So far, my code looks like this.

```
 class Investment:
    def _init_(self,p,i):
        self.p = p
        self.i = i
    def value_after(self,value,n):
        value = (1+i) ** n
        return p * value
    def _str_(self):
        return "Principal:"(p),"Investment:"(I),"%"
pr = Investment(98,3)
print(pr.value_after())
```

I expect to print Principal and Interest rate separately. At this point, I am getting the following Error

File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\principalandinterest.py", line 10, in 
    pr = Investment(98,3)
TypeError: Investment() takes no arguments

Comment: `"_init_" != "__init__"`

Comment: Can you be more specific? Should i use double underscore?

Comment: Well what does e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html say that method is called?

Comment: Most classes will have a method called __init__ . The underscores indicate that it is a special kind of method. It is called a constructor, and it is automatically called when someone creates a new object from your class. What's wrong here? Please state point of my mistake.

Comment: And *how many underscores* does the tutorial show in the name of that method?

Comment: Two Underscores? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211460/discussion-between-kalium-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This Constructer does not take arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074799/this-constructer-does-not-take-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{class Investment(object):

   def __init__(self,p,i):
     self.p = p
     self.i = i


   def value_after(self,value,n):
     value = (1+self.i) ** n
     return (self.p * value)

   def _str_(self):
     return ("Principal:"(self.p),"Investment:"(self.i),"%")}


pr = Investment(98,3)
print(pr.value_after(2,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

i and p are class attributes and can not be called like this in your methods, they should be called like self.i
Self.p

Comment: But I am getting ''Investment' object has no attribute 'p' error if I change it into self.i self.p