# Why isn't this simple code running? (copied from JournalDev)

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Here is its image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGPiD.png) this is the code

```
class Person:
    def _init_(self,n):
        self.name=n
    def get_person_name(self):
        return self.name
p1=Person("David")
p2=Person("Lisa")
print("Name",p1.get_person_name())
print("Name",p2.get_person_name())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This Constructer does not take arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074799/3744182) and also [Error when trying to use _init_ in Python 3.7.0 IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51163528/3744182).

Answer (score 2):

Your `_init_` method should be `__init__` - double underscores before and after